How to find element with querySelector on Tailwind pseudo class name
given I have radio button styled with tailwind class
<input type="radio" class="bg-red-500" checked="checked"/>

I can find the element with JavaScript query selector:
document.querySelector(".bg-red-500")

no big deal it works
But how would I find an emement styled with Tailwind's pseudo element class names?
<input type="radio" class="checked:bg-red-500" checked="checked"/>

following does not work :
document.querySelector(".checked:bg-red-500")
document.querySelector(".checked\:bg-red-500")


one more \ should do it

Search for input[class='xxx']


const dom = document.querySelector("input[class='checked:bg-red-500']");
console.log(dom)
<input type="radio" class="checked:bg-red-500" checked="checked"/>




yes this definitelly worked  great idea. However if I had element with more classes (class="checked:bg-red-500 bg-blue-100") it did not. However using *= magic will work document.querySelector("input[class*='checked:bg-red-500']");
